# I cannot get my KeyDown event to work in one project altough the exact same code works in another, older program I made (both on VS2022). Any ideas?

Tags: vb.net, keydown

My original program was created in VS2019 but also works in VS2022. The original code in the first project exists on the ONLY form in the project.

The new program was created in VS2022. The original code copy and pasted (adjusted to the new form elements) exists on the second form of the project (there are only two forms in this new project). However, this code does not seem to work at all.

Here is the code I've tried. From what I've tested it seems to be completely unresponsive. Is there a different way of handeling keydown events in VS2022?

```
    Private Sub PlayGround_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
        Select Case e.KeyCode
            Case Keys.Up
                If LeftPad.Location.Y > 0 Then
                    LeftPad.Location = New Point(LeftPad.Location.X, LeftPad.Location.Y - 15)
                End If
            Case Keys.Down
                If LeftPad.Location.Y < Me.Height - LeftPad.Height Then
                    LeftPad.Location = New Point(LeftPad.Location.X, LeftPad.Location.Y + 15)
                End If
        End Select
    End Sub
```

Comment: Why did you tag this with VBA when your code is VB.NET?

Comment: Have you used your debugger? What Control is `Me` in this context?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried using the debugger. The 'Me' here should be referencing the form.

Comment: Do you have a `Sub Overrides OnKeyDown(...)` method anywhere? Or anything that might interfere with keyboard events, such as a descendant `Control` having keyboard focus instead of the `Form`?

Comment: Sorry, I'm rather new to this and thus unfamiliar with some of those terms.  But I don't believe I have any overrides or anything that might interfere. Would I help if I were to provide all of my code (116 lines)?

Comment: only 116 lines? Don't you have a `Form.designer.vb` file too?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think to include that. I have 113 lines in the .vb and 160 in the designer.

Comment: Open Properties Window (In VS, press F4). Open Solution Explorer (In VS menu, View => Solution Explorer). In Solution Explorer, right-click "<form name>.vb" and select "View Designer". On the form, click the desired control (ex: TextBox1) to select it. In the Properties Window, click the orange/red lightning bolt. Next to "KeyDown" use the drop-down to select the correct event handler.

Comment: I've set "playground" (system.windows.forms.form) KeyDown event to PlayGround_KeyDown, but it remains unresponsive to key imput.

Comment: Forget whatever code that you've copied. You need to learn (or re-learn) how to subscribe to the `KeyDown` event. Once you've done that, you can apply it to your other code. Create a new project. Not sure what you're trying to achieve, but normally, one would be interested in handling the `KeyDown` event for a control such as a `TextBox`. If desired, one can handle `KeyDown` in the form's event handler as long as there aren't any controls on the form that would steal focus such as a TextBox.